# How can i stop Solr without stopping the WebSphere Commerce Test Server (IBM RAD)

Tags: solr, websphere-7, ibm-rad, websphere-commerce

I need to test some error handling use cases in the event that the Solr server shuts down or is unreachable. On one of our testing servers i can run the `stopServer` script passing in the indentifier for the Solr server. I have tried using the same .bat version of that script locally, but it seems there is no separate profile for Solr.

Is there a way to stop Solr only (ie. the WC instance is still running as is Apache) in RAD, either through the Admin Console, CLI script, or some other UI interface?

Comment: If you want to unload (i.e. remove) a specific core from Solr, then see: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin#UNLOAD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the WebSphere Commerce Developer, I don't believe you can do it since it's not the server deployment where it's in it's own profile.   Nevertheless, I haven't tried it but I think what you can do is block the communication ports (on server its 3737).

Comment: I didnt think of blocking the ports. What we ended up doing was changing the url configured in the `wc-search.xml` and then publishing. It was tedious but it got the job done. Port blocking probably would have been a better approach though.